# How to resolve un-registered type using standard MVC Core dependency injection

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

Is there a way to get `IServiceProvider.GetService<T>` to return an instance even if `T` is not explicitly registered with the container?

If I know that `T` has dependencies I'd like them to be injected based on their registrations without having to register `T` itself.

I believe Ninject will intelligently work out the most appropriate constructor or fallback to a parameterless constructor if no suitable constructor is found. I'd like to replicate this behaviour using the standard MVC Core DI framework if possible.

Comment: @Rafal https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/dependency-injection.html I've updated the question to MVC6 for clarity

Answer (score 54, accepted):

To keep this up to date: There is a way to achieve exactly what you are looking for.

**Standard dependency injector of .NET Core**

In my sample i create a new instance of IServiceCollection for showcase:

```
var services = new ServiceCollection();
var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
var unregisteredClassInstance = 
    ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<UnregisteredClass>(serviceProvider);
```

This gives you an instance of the type UnregisteredClass which was not previously registered, but takes constructor parameters which are registered previously on the ServiceCollection.

**Third party dependency injectors**

SimpleInjector can do that easily with 
`container.GetInstance<UnregisteredClass>();`.

Comment: I love how they took away this well known Unity "feature" to replace it with another hack.

Comment: Even so, this is not quite as powerful as other third-party DI utilities. Both the `.GetInstance<T>(..)` and `.GetServiceOrCreateInstance<T>(..)` will only work if it has a parameterless constructor OR all of its dependencies are registered. Tools such as Ninject leverage a "get service or create default instance" at every level of the dependency tree, meaning its possible to create an unregistered service which depends on other unregistered services -- not so in MS DI.

Answer (score 1):

While there is no way provided by default to resolve un-registered concrete types you can add an extension function that will give you the ability. Its important to note that this can be abused as a service locator which is an Anti-pattern. Depending on your usage its possible to take advantage of this without turning it into a service locator.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;

namespace Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
{
    public static class ServiceProviderExtensions
    {
        public static TService AsSelf<TService>(this IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return (TService)AsSelf(serviceProvider, typeof(TService));
        }
        public static object AsSelf(this IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Type serviceType)
        {
            var constructors = serviceType.GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                .Select(o => o.GetParameters())
                .ToArray()
                .OrderByDescending(o => o.Length)
                .ToArray();

            if (!constructors.Any())
            {
                return null;
            }

            object[] arguments = ResolveParameters(serviceProvider, constructors);

            if (arguments == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            return Activator.CreateInstance(serviceType, arguments);
        }

        private static object[] ResolveParameters(IServiceProvider resolver, ParameterInfo[][] constructors)
        {
            foreach (ParameterInfo[] constructor in constructors)
            {
                bool hasNull = false;
                object[] values = new object[constructor.Length];
                for (int i = 0; i < constructor.Length; i++)
                {
                    var value = resolver.GetService(constructor[i].ParameterType);
                    values[i] = value;
                    if (value == null)
                    {
                        hasNull = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!hasNull)
                {
                    // found a constructor we can create.
                    return values;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Service location is not an anti-pattern. It's an anti-pattern when you use it to not locate variable services based on the current request and instead use it as a bridge with no affordance to dynamic resolution based on the current request.

Comment: the problem with Service Locator is that it hides a class' dependencies, causing run-time errors instead of compile-time errors, as well as making the code more difficult to maintain because it becomes unclear when you would be introducing a breaking change. (http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/).

http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/15/service-locator-violates-solid/

Comment: randomly calling services.Get<MyService>() is an antipattern. Dynamic resolution of services at runtime based on variable message data is a common pattern for mechanizing process and having true reusability. Also maybe you should check before linking me posts `2012-01-31 13:54 UTC` as if i'm unaware. 6 years later i'm only more resolute than ever that service location has specific purpose. It needs deployed very carefully.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static T? BuildNoneRegisteredType<T>(this IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    var constructor = typeof(T).GetConstructors().First();
    var parameters = constructor.GetParameters();

    if (parameters is null || parameters.Length < 1)
        return Activator.CreateInstance<T>(); 

    var parametersToPas = new object?[parameters.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++)
    {
        var a = serviceProvider.GetService(parameters[i].ParameterType);
        parametersToPas[i] = a;
    }

    var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), parametersToPas);
    return obj is null ? default : (T)obj;
}
```

I use this when I have multiple databases and I dont want to use keys when resolving them. If I need a new database of type mongoDb I will do this:

```
var myMongoDb = webApp.ServiceProvider.BuildNoneRegisteredType<MongoDb>()
```