# Have dependency injection provide constructor arguments for class not registered as a service

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dependency-injection

Is there a way to use .NET Core dependency injection to create a concrete type without that type being registered as a service?

For example, say I have a `SummaryReportService` class. It is not registered as a service. However, its constructor takes several parameters that *are* registered as a service.

Is there any way to create an instance of this class and have dependency injection provide all the services needed by the constructor?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38182929/how-to-resolve-un-registered-type-using-standard-mvc-core-dependency-injection

Comment: Yeah, by registering it with the container, LOL.
Take a step back and think about what you are asking. You want the container to give you something it doesn't know about. Not going to happen. What you **can do** however, is pull the dependencies manually and call the constructor yourself.

Comment: Do the injected services need to be in the constructor? Can you take them out and create instances via service locator?

Comment: what's the real world scenario here?  Sounds like you might need to take a step back, but hard to say.

Comment: @NikitaChayka: That particular signature of `Activator.CreateInstance()` does not appear to be available in .NET Core.

Comment: @GHDevOps: I've been trying different approaches. It seems like having them in the constructor is a nice, clean approach. Do you have a link to what you're suggesting?

Comment: @JuanR: The container knows enough if I provide a concrete type. I suppose I could do it myself, although I'd probably need to get into reflection. But I wouldn't have to if .NET already supported this.

Comment: @JonathanWood Why would you want to do that? You have a container that does this for you. What's wrong wit this? `services.AddTransient(typeof(SummaryReportService));`
All you have to do it register it like so and watch the magic unfold. I guess I don't know enough about how you intend to use this.

Comment: @JuanR: Yes, I can do that. It's just that I have a number of such objects that will be created dynamically and I want it to be easy to add, remove and change them. I thought this might be supported since most of the functionality is already in place.

Comment: @JonathanWood the types would need to known at compile time for what you are asking and it wouldn't be very efficient. If by "dynamically" you mean you are activating objects from external libraries, you can request the child dependencies from the container manually and use them to activate the object.

Comment: First comment answers this question it seems, though not sure if that's a duplicate. It is supported in many DI containers since as you said there is no problem in theory to resolve such service, but not in . NET "native" DI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you are not doing a good design. But, I found cases in wich I had to do something like that. You will need a reference to the IServiceProvider, and do something like:

```
var summaryReportService = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(this.serviceProvider, typeof(SummaryReportService));
```

It will create a instance of SummaryReportService with the required dependencies (if configured).